# Which type of mosfet used to make CMOS inverter?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, vlsi

My doubt is which type of mosfet used to make CMOS inverter Enhancement or depletion ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enhancement

Very few applications need to use depletion MOSFETs. And only a few models are available, all of one polarity.

So, yes, Enhancement MOSFET.